# Change radio button background image C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, radio-button

I want to edit and change a radio button's background image.
I want it to happen on-going while the program is running but I can't find the correct code to do that.
Surely I can not do it through the easy way via properties because I need it to happen live.
I am using VisualStudio winforms.
THANKS!

```
void RandomRB(string[] answers, string[] images)
    {
        int[] randarray = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            // To make sure there are no crossing indexes
            randarray[i] = -1;
        }
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int random;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            random = rnd.Next(0, 3);
            // To make sure that the random index hasn't been used before
            if (randarray.Contains(random))
                i--;
            else
                randarray[i] = random;
        }
        rb1.Text = answers[randarray[0]];
        // I want to insert a picture from string[] images
        rb1.BackgroundImage = ???
        rb2.Text = answers[randarray[1]];
        rb1.BackgroundImage = ???
        rb3.Text = answers[randarray[2]];
        rb1.BackgroundImage = ???
    }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page - Do you want an animation? Winforms: Use a Timer.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I want the radio-button's background image to change according to the question. Let's say it's a trivia game and the player has to click on the correct radiobutton

Comment: What does *surely I can not do it via properties* mean? Of course you can set a property at run-time. What's the problem with the `BackgroundImage` property?

Comment: I need the command to do it. I mean to do it via the property window. I am new in coding so it's hard for me to explain. I wonder if there's a code looking something like that: radiobutton.BackgroundImage = ("something")

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you would write. Try and come back if you run into issues..

Comment: What is that "something" that l have to type? I really don't know and can't manage to find the answer...

Comment: That *something* is an Image reference. It could be `Properties.Resources.SomeImage`, a Bitmap you have loaded beforehand from a File or any other source. You should build a `List<Bitmap>` (or similar collection), add the Bitmap you want to use to this collection and assign one of these Bitmap to a `[Control].Image` property whenever you need to. Remember to `Dispose()` of the previous Image, if any (e.g., `myControl.Image?.Dispose(); myControl.Image = myListOfImages[1];`).

Comment: Thank you Jimi very much! What if I have that photo in the same folder? Can I load it with a route string? If so, what do I type in the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want the background image and text of the radiobutton to dynamically change.
You can try the following code to solve your problem.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Interval = 1000;       
            radioButton1.BackgroundImageLayout =ImageLayout.Stretch;
        }
        string[] path = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\Picture");
        string[] answers = {"AA","BB",  "CC", "DD", "EE","FF"};
        Random r1 = new Random();
        Random r2 = new Random();       
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
            radioButton1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(path[r1.Next(0,path.Length)]);
            radioButton1.Text =answers[r2.Next(0, answers.Length)];
        }
```

Result:

[image]